# "This LFS object could not be found."

Tags: github, git-clone, git-lfs

I am a part of a development team working on a Unity game project hosted on GitHub.
The project uses Git LFS to handle large binary files, such as textures, 3D models, and audio assets.

I navigated to the directory where I want to clone the repository and initiated the clone command:

git clone https://github.com/my-username/game-project.git

The repository should be cloned successfully, including all the large binary files managed by Git LFS and I should be able to access the game project's code and assets locally.

However, Instead of successfully cloning the repository, I am encounter an error related to Git LFS.

Error Message: "Smudge error: Error downloading game_assets/textures/level1_bg.png: batch response: This LFS object could not be found."

Please guide!

The repository should have been cloned successfully, including all the large binary files managed by Git LFS. I should have been able to access the game project's code and assets locally. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check version of git LFS using command

```
git lfs version
```

Verify that your local repository's Git LFS has been initialized. The following command can be used to verify:

```
git lfs install
```

Run this command to initialize Git LFS if it hasn't already:

```
git lfs install --local
```

Then run this to clear the cache

```
git lfs cache --clear
```

There can be discrepancies in your local repository if you've used Git LFS to clone the repository many times. Starting from scratch with a new clone is preferable, so run this command:

```
rm -rf game-project
git clone https://github.com/my-username/game-project.git
```

Hope this will solve your issue